# How to convert number into currency field?

Tags: process-builder, data-types

I am trying to update currency field with number field in a Process builder. However i get an error data type mismatch. Is it possible to do type conversion here. Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You need to Use TEXT() function for this.

*It Converts a percent, number, date, date/time, or currency type field into text anywhere formulas are used. Also, converts picklist values to text in approval rules, approval step rules, workflow rules, escalation rules, assignment rules, auto-response rules, validation rules, formula fields, field updates, and custom buttons and links.*

e.g. Lets Say I am converting Amount Field(Type: Currency) into Number then I can create a formula like this:

> VALUE(TEXT(Amount))

The reason that I am using VALUE() here is because it converts my text string into Number.You can not directly convert your currency into Number.

Try to add this formula in your process builder.

Check the below link for more details:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions.htm&type=0

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Hi Patil,  I need conversion from number to Currency. Thanks for the explanation though.

Comment: Do u have multiple currencies enable in your org?

Answer (score 0):

Number to Currency conversion:
Create a formula field with return type Currency and insert the number field within. Then update the Currency field with this formula field in the Process builder.